# JQM collapsible header with image

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

Hello guys I have a problem...

I use collapsible set in my JQM 1.4 page...

In the header I want to have text on the left and an image on the right ...

i used this piece of code

```
<h3>Sectionit ' + naslov + '<img src="images/'+slika+'" width="150" height="150" style="float:right;" /></h3>
```

and this is what happens...

http://oi44.tinypic.com/s1uwjl.jpg

How do I make the text to be vertical aligned  in center ???

thanks

Answer (score 2):

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/uaK9f/)**

Just make the line height the same as the image height:

```
h3 .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
    line-height: 150px;
}
```

NOTE: this only works for single lines of text...

Comment: so there is no other chance to do this :( pitty :(

Comment: what do you mean? in the fiddle, the text is vertically centered.